# Php contained inside HTML inside PHP

Tags: php

Having a bit of an issue with PHP thats contained inside HTML thats inside PHP.

I have a script running that's using an SQL query to obtain Titles, Storys, urls (etc.)

Then

```
<?php
#Random code here to obtain SQL results
#$id = $row['id'];  
#$story_Title["$id"] = $row['story_Title'];
#end of random code block for reference

echo '<!-- BEGIN content -->
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
<p class="details1">$date["{$id}"]/(echo $story_Title["{$id}"];)
```

The code :

```
$date["{$id}"]
```

Is printing to the web page literally , as apposed to returning the results requested.

Is there anyway to get around this , or is it not possible.

If not possible, what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the string with `.`:

```
<?php
echo '
<!-- BEGIN content -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <p class="details1">'.$date[$row['id']].'/'.$story_Title[$row['id']].'</p>
    </div>
</div>';
?>
```

Or you can break in and out of PHP like:

```
<!-- BEGIN content -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <p class="details1">
        <?php
            echo $date[$row['id']].'/'.$story_Title[$row['id']];
        ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Read about, [String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

> There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation
>   operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left
>   arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='),
>   which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the
>   left side.

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with this?

```
<?php
    // some php code here...
?>

<!-- BEGIN content -->
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
<p class="details1">

<?php
    echo $date[$row['id']] . '/' . $story_Title[$row['id']];
?>

</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is an HTML 'templating' language as well as a programming language.

When you have sizable amounts of HTML to send then i suggest you start using PHP in that 'mode'. Never echo 'lots' of HTML in 'chunks'. Just drop out of PHP mode and 'switch' in and out of PHP mode as required. It is a lot easier...

You are also working rather hard when accessing stuff. All the PHP code in a script is linked together so your '$row' variable is available with direct access from mostly everywhere.

```
the  '<?= ' is short for '<?php echo ', it is always available.
```

If you want to do 'control statements' like 'if, foreach etc' then look at the **[control-structures.alternative-syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)**

Tested code:

```
<?php
#Random code here to obtain SQL results
$row = array('id' => 1, 'story_Title' => 'how to do stuff!', 'date' => '1960-04-01');
#end of random code block for reference

?>
<!-- BEGIN content -->
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">
            <p class="details1"><?= $row['date']?>/(<?= $row['story_Title']?>)</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Output from the above code:

```
1960-04-01/(how to do stuff!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// inside a loop run this 
 echo '<!-- BEGIN content -->
    <div id="content">
     <div class="post">
      <p class="details1">',
        $row['date'], $row['id']
      '<h1>', $row['story_Title'] , '</h1>',
     '</p>
     </div>
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure variables inside single quotes are actually not within single quotes.

```
echo '<!-- BEGIN content -->
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
<p class="details1">' . $date["{$id}"] . '</p';
```

[See this for detailed  explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)